# Routing and View in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes

Am new to angularjs.Am trying to use route the page to respective view .But nothing is displayed on page.Console is not showing any errors.
Below is code of controller.

Plnkr link : http://plnkr.co/edit/1s0PllXVnFHcV063srAt?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'customersController',
    templateUrl: 'customers.html'
  }).when('/orders/:customerId', {
    controller: 'ordersController',
    templateUrl: 'orders.html'
  }).otherwise({
    'redirectTo': '/'
  });

});

app.controller('customersController', function($scope) {

  $scope.sortBy = 'name';
  $scope.reverse = false;

  $scope.customers = [{
    id:1,
    name: 'James',
    city: 'Seattle',
    orderTotal: 9.546,
    joined: '2012-02-05',
    orders:[{
      id:1,
      product:'Shoes',
      total:9.9665
    }]
  }, {
    id:2,
    name: 'Sarah',
    city: 'Dallas',
    orderTotal: 3.653,
    joined: '2010-08-07',
    orders:[{
      id:2,
      product:'Sandal',
      total:8.3465
    }]
  }, {
    id:3,
    name: 'Tom',
    city: 'Troy',
    orderTotal: 8.346,
    joined: '2011-04-09',
    orders:[{
      id:3,
      product:'Sneakers',
      total:6.3427
    }]
  }, {
    id:4,
    name: 'Ling',
    city: 'Columbus',
    orderTotal: 5.549,
    joined: '2014-03-10',
    orders:[{
      id:4,
      product:'belt',
      total:8.9674
    }]
  }];

  $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
    $scope.sortBy = propName;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
  };

});
```

Comment: also make sure that your `templarUrl: 'path/example/index.html'` paths from your `index.html` page, not from where ever your javascript is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'customersController',
    templateUrl: 'customers.html'
  }).when('/orders/:customerId', {
    controller: 'ordersController',
    templateUrl: 'orders.html'
  }).otherwise({
    'redirectTo': '/'
  });

}]);

app.controller('customersController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.sortBy = 'name';
  $scope.reverse = false;

  $scope.customers = [{
    id:1,
    name: 'James',
    city: 'Seattle',
    orderTotal: 9.546,
    joined: '2012-02-05',
    orders:[{
      id:1,
      product:'Shoes',
      total:9.9665
    }]
  }, {
    id:2,
    name: 'Sarah',
    city: 'Dallas',
    orderTotal: 3.653,
    joined: '2010-08-07',
    orders:[{
      id:2,
      product:'Sandal',
      total:8.3465
    }]
  }, {
    id:3,
    name: 'Tom',
    city: 'Troy',
    orderTotal: 8.346,
    joined: '2011-04-09',
    orders:[{
      id:3,
      product:'Sneakers',
      total:6.3427
    }]
  }, {
    id:4,
    name: 'Ling',
    city: 'Columbus',
    orderTotal: 5.549,
    joined: '2014-03-10',
    orders:[{
      id:4,
      product:'belt',
      total:8.9674
    }]
  }];

  $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
    $scope.sortBy = propName;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
  };

}]);
```

Anytime i'm using a built in angular service, I include the array syntaxx `['$routeProvider', '$scope', function($routeProvider, $scope) {}];`

Answer (score 0):

Get the module like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

and only create myApp module once:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LjN94ejEXVI2tktC86M1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @ gyantasaurus